# How to implement CallKit alike behaviour on Android with react native?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, voip, callkit

I have an application written in react-native to handle Voip calls between users. I need to wakeup the app upon push notification and show a screen to accept/decline the call.

On iOS there is [callkit](https://github.com/ianlin/react-native-callkit), is there anything similar for Android?

Comment: Generally speaking, sounds like just a `BroadcastReceiver` would work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some researches, I've come up with a solution which integrates some native Android code with the native app. First of all I've used **WakefulBroadcastReceiver** to wake up our activity process after receiving a push notification, then with a Service I start the ReactActivity and show the custom screen written in Java to handle accept/decline of the call.

I've written a [blog post](https://belkadigital.com/it/articles/callkit-android-react-native/) about it with an in-depth example.

Comment: Hello, can you post source code for react native android on github? I have follow the code on your blog post, but unfortunately my app didn't work. I believe I miss something on Java side, and it's very helpful to compare with 
 your source code. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @PewhGosh at the moment I'm not able to generate a proper example for github (lacking of time)  Could you post here your error? So I'd try to help you out

Comment: I'm unable to follow the blog post due to same reason. A Github repository will be really helpful

Comment: @DaniAkash Could you give me some other info on your error? I'd like to help you but atm I'm not able to create a repo on git :(

Comment: Hello @FabrizioRizzonelli, in PusherReceiver class, why `notificationData` variable is init but not used? And then, can I redirect to React Native view (by using react-native-navigation router) automatically instead of create custom XML UI on UnlockScreenActivity? I must access React Native view because I can access redux, that unfortunately cannot be done by native android

Comment: I'm also curious, does it work if on UnlockScreenActivity's onCreate, it trigger deep-link automatically (then open RN view) instead of show `setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_incoming)`? I don't use react-native-navigation here. And will the phone turn the screen off again using deep-link method (when state is lock screen)?

Comment: @PewhGosh In my use case I was using react-native-navigation, so some choice are taken because I'm using that library. That said, I don't think you can directly show a RN view on custom screen, maybe you can use native Android to trigger the rendering of a RN view, but I didn't try that :)

Comment: @PewhGosh Btw, why do you need redux in your "answer call view"? Can't you just pass the data needed through native events? I don't think that view need to interact with redux state, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Fabrizio Rizzonelli i need to ask one question first thanks for such great article which helped alot , in the artical i followed u greatly but i got stuck  when u extend NatigationActivity i donot use  wix nativigation so what should i extend instead of NatigationActivity and we dont have to create new MainApplication file right ? we just have to use the existed MainApplication file which is generated by default ? and forgive me if u think that i asked stupid question cuz i am not an java developer

Comment: @MuhammadShaheem Thank you, really appreciated :) Btw you should extend the default Activity generated from RN, and also edit the MainApplication.java, don't create a new one!

Comment: @Fabrizio Rizzonelli is there any way to receive intent in mainApplication which i passed in MainActivity ?

Comment: @Fabrizio Rizzonelli if i can get my intent which i passed in MainActivity 
i can use my react-native activity easily with some conditions like setting some flag for my MianActivity

Comment: @MuhammadShaheem It depends, are you using any library for navigation?

Comment: @FabrizioRizzonelli yes i am using react-navigation

Comment: @FabrizioRizzonelli **WakefulBroadcastReceiver** is deprecated now. I'm using **react-native** and **react-native-pjsip** library for handling VoIP as well as **react-native-push-notification** system but not able to figure it out for notification in case of App is not awake. PS: I'm new in mobile native app development and not familiar with java