# React Native - Show incoming video call screen in Android (VOIP app)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, twilio, webrtc

I am trying to implement **video calling** feature in react native app. I have used [React native twilio video webrtc](https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc). I have implemented the same and got it working.

I don't exactly know the flow of Video calling in mobile apps. 
The flow which I am using for video calling is as follows:

1. User 1 taps to call User 2
2. Your app generates a unique name for a Room. Perhaps a combination of the two user's IDs.
3. User 1 connects to Room with generated unique name
4. Using FCM, send message of high priority with the unique name of the Room and token to User 2
5. **User 2 to receives notification and you display a ringing UI(even when the app is killed and phone is locked)**
6. User 2 accepts and connects to the same Room

Now I am stuck on point 5.
I am sending the FCM notification(which shows up in tray **(edit: now using voip notif**) to user2 and ***now I need to show ringing UI on user2's mobile even if the app is killed and phone is locked.*** How can I achieve this?

I guess there is a package called [react-native-callkit](https://github.com/ianlin/react-native-callkit/releases), which I should be using along with [PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit) for the same. But the problem is with android flow. PushKit and CallKit is not supported in android. So, when app is in killed state the notification appears I need to grab the control and display ringing UI and wake the screen if the phone is locked and app is killed.

**Some Confusions**

Is there any special type of push notification which doesn't get displayed in the tray? **(edit: data messages and VOIP notif I guess)**

Is there any other package than [react-native-callkit](https://github.com/ianlin/react-native-callkit/releases)(for displaying ringing UI) which can be used for both android and ios?

Comment: Refer this solution for showing incoming Video screen:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46113511/1635587

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Android doesn't have `CallKit`, but it does provide the [`ConnectionService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService) to allow you to build incoming call screen notifications. There's not a lot I can find that connects `ConnectionService` with React Native, so you may have to check out the [Android examples](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged#connection-service) and build this yourself.

Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Hi Phil, I wonder if you know of any apps in the app store that are using react native with the Twilio Video service, I am wanting to evaluate if the performance is ok relative to native apps... Maybe you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi @exrhizo, I don't know specifically if there are any React Native Twilio Video apps, but I do know that there is a [community maintained library that implements Twilio Video in React Native](https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc). They might be worth asking if they have live apps.

Answer (score 0):

I was following the example from Twilio https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android and then it worked well, even my project in React-Native.